# How to bind a route url for form tag in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

## This is my form tag

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url("/post/{$article->id}/comment") }}">>
```

## This is my route

```
    Route::post('/post/{article}/comment', 'CommentController@store');
```

## This is my commentcontroller method

```
    public function store(Article $article)
        {
             $comment = $article->comment->create([
            'body' => request('body'),
            ]);
            return back();
        }
```

## show.blade.php

```
`@extends('master')
@section('content')
<!-- Example row of columns -->
<div class="container">
    <h1> {{ $articles->title }} </h1>
    <p> {{ $articles->body }} </p>
    <hr></hr>
    <div class="comment">
        <ul class="list-group"> 
            @foreach($articles->comments as $comment)
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <strong>
                    {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans()}} : &nbsp;
                </strong>
                {{ $comment->body }}
            </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Here is comment form -->
    <hr>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ url ("/post/{$article->id}/comment") }}">> 
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="body" placeholder="your comment here." class="form-control">  </textarea>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        @include('partials.errors')
    </div>
</div>
@endsection`
```

When I'm trying to add comment on article I'm getting an error like this:

```
> Undefined variable: article (View: C:\xampp7\htdocs\Lara\resources\views\article\show.blade.php)
```

Anything wrong in this? help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not passing `$article` to view. You haven't included the code but you have somewhere something like this:

```
return view('article.show');
```

and instead you should have:

```
return view('article.show', compact('article'));
```

so finally your `show` method in controller should look something like this:

```
public function show(Article $article)
{
    return view('article.show', compact('article'));
}
```

Comment: I'm just trying to add a comment on article. because of form action I'm unable to see my article. It is simply throwing an error like Undefined variable: article (View: C:\xampp7\htdocs\Lara\resources\views\article\show.blade.php)

Comment: @steven But you are not showing the valid action code. You are getting error in action where you display article using `article.show` view and in `store` action you are not displaying the view, you are only redirecting back

Comment: articlecontroller@show method    ```public function show($id)
    {
        $posts = Article::find($id);

        return view('article.show',compact('posts'));
    }```

Comment: @steven so you have error here, you assign article to `$posts` variable and not article, try with `show` method I've showed.

Comment: `public function show(Article $articleId)
    {
        $articles = Article::find($articleId);

        return view('article.show',compact('articles'));
    }`    Does it make sense @Marcin

Comment: No, it doesn't you already have article, so you don't need to take it from database one more time it at all.

Comment: Oh gosh got new errors ```Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp7\htdocs\Lara\resources\views\article\show.blade.php)``` I will post my entire show.blade.php

Comment: show.blade.php   ```@extends('master')

@section('content')
<!-- Example row of columns -->

<div class="container">

 <h1> {{ $articles->title }} </h1>

 <p> {{ $articles->body }} </p>

 <hr></hr>

 <div class="comment">

  <ul class="list-group"> 

   @foreach($articles->comments as $comment)

   <li class="list-group-item">

    <strong>

     {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans()}} : &nbsp;

    </strong>

    {{ $comment->body }}

   </li>

   @endforeach

  </ul>

 </div>```

Comment: @steven Notice that in one place you are using `$article` and in other in same view `$articles`. Use same variable name in the whole view that will match variable name passed from controller

Comment: I modified all the things even though. I'm getting same thing. If possible can you visit my github repo..

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are calling your article `$articles` (plural) when in fact it is a single article.

in your controller change `$articles` to `$article` and then change it in the view where you have articles, for instance `$articles->body`.  It will then be correct when you use it in the form action.